# ITERATOR LIST CORRUPTED in std::string constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2005, visual-c++-2008

The code below compiled in Debug configuration in VS2005 SP1 shows two messages with “ITERATOR LIST CORRUPTED” notice.

Code Snippet

```
#define _SECURE_SCL 0
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << "123" << std::endl;
  std::string str = stream.str();
  std::string::const_iterator itFirst = str.begin();
  int position = str.find('2');
  std::string::const_iterator itSecond = itFirst + position;
  std::string tempStr(itFirst,itSecond); ///< errors are here
  return 0;
}
```

Is it a bug in the compiler or standard library?

Comment: Happens to me on VS2008 as well. Fascinating.

Comment: Consider using codepad.org for testing against gcc quickly: http://codepad.org/mXXYxf99  this is definitely a windows/visual studio bug. please report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @dirkgently said in his edit.

Apparently, some code for `std::string` is located in the runtime dll, in particular the macro definition does not take effect for the constructor an the code for iterator debugging gets executed. You can fix this by linking the runtime library statically.

I would consider this a bug, though perhaps not in the Visual Studio itself, but in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

My bad! Edit: Yeah problem with compiler. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939%28VS.80%29.aspx) -- particularly the Community Content section.

Comment: What do you mean? `std::string` does have random-access iterators.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code. Well, several in fact:

1. `std.find('2')` returns a `size_t`, you have a potential cast problem if the value of the `size_t` returned (like `std::string::npos`) is superior to what an `int` can hold (you would end up with a negative int I think...)
2. if `position` is negative, or equal to `std::string::npos` then the range `itFirst,itSecond` is ill-defined (either because `itSecond` is before `itFirst` or because it is past `str.end()`)

Correct your code, and check if it stills throw. Iterator Debugging is here to help you catch these mistakes, disabling it acting like an ostrich.

Comment: The string version of find() actually returns a std::string::size_type.

Comment: Generally you are right, but in this specific case `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is switched off. If you set `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` to 1 there will be no errors. Thus, seems to be a bug in CRT.

Comment: @Neil: true, and most containers effectively use an inner typedef `size_type` for all indexing purpose, which I have never seen being other than `size_t` in the (few) implementations of the STL I have come upon. The real problem is that most often that not it's an unsigned value (since indexing in negative does not make sense, unless you are using sweet Python).